# Searching for a unique value associated with a category that is duplicated

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is my first time diving into excel and I'm currently trying to create a formula that finds the highest score in a certain category. I've left out some data for privacy reasons, and because it's not needed. Also, keep in mind this document has 677 names total.
Here are the events and names:
[image: Here are the events and names]

Here are some scores:
[image: Here are some scores]

I've tried using this formula as a test,

```
=IF(A:A="Accounting",VLOOKUP(LARGE(D:D,1),A:D,2,FALSE),0)
```

But it doesn't work like I thought it would. I want to be able to search for the highest score for Accounting, for example, and then the output the name of the person who made that score. I've also considered using MATCH, INDEX, and CHOOSE functions, but I'm not sure how to put together the logic. Any assistance or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAXIFS` function. For example based on the image below, F2 has the following formula to find the criteria "Accounting" (from E2):

```
=MAXIFS(C1:C6,A1:A6,E2)
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I've been racking my brain for 3 days trying to figure out the right function to use. This works perfectly!

Comment: @Don If your questions has been answered successfully, please mark it as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your post that you wanted the name of the person with the highest score also, which seemed to missed in the other answer.

If you still want show who achieved the max score try this formula in cell "G2" for accounting.

```
=INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(E2&F2,A1:A6&C1:C6,0))
```

& this formula in cell "G3" for Statistics

```
=INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(E3&F3,A1:A6&C1:C6,0))
```

It matches the high score from the different sections & returns the person associated with that score.